# Is Code Lens available on Visual Studio 2013 Community?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to know if it is possible to activate code lens in visual studio 2013 community or not, because it is a feature that I like.

Comment: Strangely, it is available on Visual Code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not. The community edition is equal to Professional.

Code Lens is available in Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: Code Lens is in Professional **2015**, but not in Community
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx